# Can total least squares be used to account for uncertainty due to measurement timing?

Tags: regression, measurement-error, total-least-squares, longitudinal-data-analysis

Suppose we have a dataset in which we wish to perform regression analysis, and where the response/dependent variable is a measurement at time *T*. But due to pragmatic sampling we do not have measurements at precisely *T* for all observations. Let's say observations occur at *T*+*δ*<sub>1</sub>, *T*+*δ*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *T*+*δ<sub>n</sub>* (and such that *δ*<sub>i</sub> = 0 is a possibility).

For example, suppose we want to model the drug levels measured in patient blood samples at six weeks (42 days) after starting treatment with a drug. But in practice patient follow-ups occur at a range of dates: 37 days, 41 days, 42 days, 39 days, 52 days, ... etc.

- Would Total Least Squares regression be an appropriate way to account for the uncertainty in the dependent variable?

  - If so, how would one go about specifying an appropriate weighting scheme based on the *δ* values?
  - If not, what would be a better approach?

In case it makes a difference: we are particularly interested in testing for a relationship with some particular independent variable (e.g. dose), but will also need to account for covariates (e.g. BMI). Also, for *some* subjects we have multiple observations of the dependent variable over time, so could in theory derive a range for how quickly the dependent variable can change in general (e.g. we can get an average daily change in drug level over some time periods for some patients).